# Fetching an Integer From CoreData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have fetched a result from core data in my app and need to get the integer value of its 'capacity' attribute I gave it.

The 'capacity' attribute is an NSInteger 16 in my core data model.

I get my result like so:

```
entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TableInfo" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tablesArray objectAtIndex:row]]]];

    NSArray *selectedTableFetched = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Now my problem is how do I get the 'capacity' value from my result? I know there is a result as I have check the count of the array and I have tried this:

```
NSNumber *n = [selectedTableFetched valueForKey:@"capacity"];
```

It gives me something, when accessing the NSNumber I get a meaningless long number, so if I try and access the integer value like so:

```
[n integerValue]
```

it crashes the app and I get this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x138870'
```

All I need to do is get that integer value from the capacity attribute.

Comment: I think `[selectedTableFetched valueForKey:@"capacity"]` does not return an `NSNumber` but an `NSArray`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`selectedTableFetched` is an array:

```
NSArray *selectedTableFetched = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

So you want to work with an element (presumably the only element, based on your `fetchRequest`'s predicate) before you do `valueForKey`:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [selectedTableFetched lastObject];
NSNumber *n = [managedObject valueForKey:@"capacity"];
NSInteger *yourInteger = [n integerValue];
```

Comment: Creating an instance of my managed object did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to assign an Integer to a Number type 
Try chaing the line

```
NSNumber *n = [selectedTableFetched valueForKey:@"capacity"];
```

To

```
NSInteger *n = [selectedTableFetched valueForKey:@"capacity"];
```

Comment: Error: `Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') is disallowed with ARC`